# project Can not execute Findbugs: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, findbugs, jdk1.8-73

I am using sonarQube4.5.7 version with JDK 1.8 version. currently getting this error on running

```
mvn sonar:sonar
```

command. can anyone suggest me how to resolve this error.

Logs are:

```
Unable to get XClass for java/lang/StringBuilder
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 26721
At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)
At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:110)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassParserUsingASM.parse(ClassParserUsingASM.java:587)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:76)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.XFactory.getXClass(XFactory.java:652)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addInheritanceEdge(Subtypes2.java:1260)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addSupertypeEdges(Subtypes2.java:1233)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addClassAndGetClassVertex(Subtypes2.java:275)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.ch.Subtypes2.addClass(Subtypes2.java:244)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.ba.AnalysisContext.setAppClassList(AnalysisContext.java:941)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.setAppClassList(FindBugs2.java:997)
At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:225)
At org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:207)
At java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
At java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have hit bug [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=457949). Try with jdk 7 or upgrade findbug pluguin.