# ERROR: Can not execute Findbugs -ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-4.5

When i ran sonar scan i am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in find-bugs because of this problem sonar scan is failing .
Can anyone please help resolving this issue ?

**Logs:**

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>  ERROR: Can not
>   execute Findbugs
>  ERROR: Caused by:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 27528
>  ERROR: Caused by:
>   27528

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 27528
  At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
  At org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.<init>(FBClassReader.java:35)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:47)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.asm.ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassReaderAnalysisEngine.java:34)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:72)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.engine.ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.analyze(ClassInfoAnalysisEngine.java:38)
  At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.classfile.impl.AnalysisCache.getClassAnalysis(AnalysisCache.java:268)
```

**Version of sonar**

> sonarQube  Version 4.5
>  sonar-scanner-2.5.1 
>  java code complied
>   in JRE-1.8 version

Comment: you may want to try using asm-debug-all, as opposed to the minified asm.jar so that you get line numbers in those exception stack traces

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120949/project-can-not-execute-findbugs-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception) solution may help you.